# THREE.Sprite + fog || THREE.ParticleSystem + array of texture maps

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a particle system using Sprite, but the problem is Sprite does not seem to respond to the "fog" parameter (ie. it doesn't fade away with distance). I could use ParticleSystem instead of using many Sprites (as ParticleSystem does respect the fog parameter) but I need each particle to have a different texture map. So neither method achieves both :(

Does anyone know how to either:
a/ Get Sprite working with fog
b/ Get ParticleSystem working with an array of texture maps

? Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't working because fog wasn't implemented for Sprite objects.

I just added it, you can try my dev branch:

https://github.com/alteredq/three.js/commit/9c3194b9e1e5ce7ff9f3e36842a7e51f7ae21232

With this, Sprites should now get fogged if you set `sprite.fog = true`